# Why do I need to select twice in order to update state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Select component, which is basically a dropdown. When I choose one of it's item I see that id doesn't change and still remains of the previously selected item's id. but if I re-select it again then id updates.

Here is the code

```
    const EditBookingDetailsModal = () => {
      const { modals, toggleModal, T } = useUI()
      const { laundry } = useLaundryContext()
      const { currentReservation, handleRecalculateReservationAmount, setState} = useReservationsContext()
      const {  vehicleBodyTypeId } = currentReservation as IReservationDetails
      const bodyTypes: ICarBodyType[] = laundry?.bodyTypes || []
      const [vehicleBodyId, setVehicleBodyId] = useState(vehicleBodyTypeId)
      const generateBodyTypesOptions = () => bodyTypes.map((bodyType) => ({
        label: bodyType.name,
        value: bodyType.id
      }))
      return (
        <Modal
          isOpen={modals.editReservationDetailsModal.isOpened}
          onClose={() => {
            toggleModal("editReservationDetailsModal", false)
            setState({ modifiedPrice: null })
          }}
          title={T("booking.details.edit.modal.title")}
          styles={{
            headerPadding: "20px 15px 20px 23px",
            width: "566px",
            bodyPadding: "0px 0px 0px 0px",
          }}
        >
          <Box paddingBottom={"40px"}>
            <Flex
              gap={"30px"}
              padding="14px 23px 20px 23px"
              borderBottom={"1px solid #E9F2FD "}
            >
              <FormControl width={"55%"}>
                <FormLabel id="auto" text={T("booking.details.edit.auto")} />
                <Select
                  value={vehicleBodyId|| ""}
                  onChange={(e: any) => {
                    setVehicleBodyId(e.value)
                      handleRecalculateReservationAmount(3, 4, vehicleBodyId)
                  }}
                  options={generateBodyTypesOptions()}
                  inputStyles={{
                    height: "60px",
                  }}
                  // placeholderStyles={{ fontSize: "var(--chakra-fontSizes-m)" }}
                  
                />  
              </FormControl>
            </Flex>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      )
}
```

This is greatly reduced code and minimal example where this behavior still occurs. Main thing is happening in `onChange` attribute.
I wanna know why `vehicleBodyId` doesn't update on the first click.

Comment: VehicleBodyId will not change immediately after calling setVehicleBodyId.  It will change on re-render.  Could you pass e.value to the handle function instead?

Comment: I have passed e.value directly and it works fine, but i need to use that e.value outside this Select Component so that's why i need some global variable with that value. I have two another Select components and i have to use that e.value there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const EditBookingDetailsModal = () => {
      const { modals, toggleModal, T } = useUI()
      const { laundry } = useLaundryContext()
      const { currentReservation, handleRecalculateReservationAmount, setState} = useReservationsContext()
      const {  vehicleBodyTypeId } = currentReservation as IReservationDetails
      const bodyTypes: ICarBodyType[] = laundry?.bodyTypes || []
      // const [vehicleBodyId, setVehicleBodyId] = useState(vehicleBodyTypeId)
      const generateBodyTypesOptions = () => bodyTypes.map((bodyType) => ({
        label: bodyType.name,
        value: bodyType.id
      }))
      return (
        <Modal
          isOpen={modals.editReservationDetailsModal.isOpened}
          onClose={() => {
            toggleModal("editReservationDetailsModal", false)
            setState({ modifiedPrice: null })
          }}
          title={T("booking.details.edit.modal.title")}
          styles={{
            headerPadding: "20px 15px 20px 23px",
            width: "566px",
            bodyPadding: "0px 0px 0px 0px",
          }}
        >
          <Box paddingBottom={"40px"}>
            <Flex
              gap={"30px"}
              padding="14px 23px 20px 23px"
              borderBottom={"1px solid #E9F2FD "}
            >
              <FormControl width={"55%"}>
                <FormLabel id="auto" text={T("booking.details.edit.auto")} />
                <Select
                  value={vehicleBodyId|| ""}
                  onChange={(e: any) => {
                    // don't use useState hook if you want to pass the value directly, use a regular variable
                    // setVehicleBodyId(e.value)
                    const selectCurrentValue = e.value // this will work
                      handleRecalculateReservationAmount(3, 4, selectCurrentValue)
                  }}
                  options={generateBodyTypesOptions()}
                  inputStyles={{
                    height: "60px",
                  }}
                  // placeholderStyles={{ fontSize: "var(--chakra-fontSizes-m)" }}
                  
                />  
              </FormControl>
            </Flex>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      )
}
```

- Instead of using the useState to take the value just pass the current
  value to the function handling
- useState hook is a closure function, that doesn't take the value
  directly after setting a new one, the state value will take the new
  value after re-render happen
- the solution is to use the normal JavaScript variable (check the onChange attribute)

Comment: It works but the thing is that i need to use that normal JavaScript variable outside too, I have two another Select Components and i need that there, so how to get around this ?